# How can I log in with a redirect post request to login method in laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, request

I'm trying to make an api which allows an app to log in with a click, but `laravel` doesn't maintain the session after login. I tried to use passport but failed. Now I'm trying to fake a login with a redirect to the login method, sending it parameters with a redirect type `POST`, but it redirects me to the login page after it fails.

Here's the code:

```
        $myRequest = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();
        $myRequest->setMethod('POST');
        $myRequest->request->add(['_token' => Session::token(),'name'=>'user','password'=>'password,'login'=>'']);
      return redirect()->action(
            'Auth\LoginController@login', $myRequest
      );
```

Comment: What do you mean by `laravel doesn't maintain the session after login`? Basically there's a lot of "it don't work" and nothing for us to go on at all.

Comment: APIs don't use `session()`; it's a new connection every time a request is made, which is why you send a token generated from the Server; so the API knows who you are.